# Download file web with Python

Tags: python, automation

I need help with an automation task I'm working on. In one of the steps, I need to extract a dataset from the internet. Currently, I do this manually: I access the page containing multiple files, select the desired file using the selection option, and then click the download button, which is located near the bottom of the page.

I would like to know if it's possible to do this in Python. When I already have the direct download link, it's easy, but now, with the need to interact with the web page to select the file and click the download button, I'm facing difficulties.

An interesting addition would be the ability to select not only the desired file but also the date of the last update. On the website, this information is presented in rows as follows:

File name | Selection box | Date selection field | Last update information.

Is it possible to automatically verify the date of the last update and populate the date selection field with this information?

Comment: How can you see exactly what difficulties you are facing? Post at least one line of your code, please.

Comment: @СергейКох I placed a snippet of the code in one of the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Selenium, you can do that. Get the url page, then find clickable element, and finally, by click(). If you specify the url and which file you want to download, I could help more.

These are you need:

```
from selenium import webdriver # creating a web object
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or firefox and...
driver.get(url_link)

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By # locate clickable element
driver.find_element(By.???, ???)
driver.click()
```

and last request:
You should locate this information like above (File name | Selection box | Date selection field | Last update information) and depends on type of them, you can get them as text.

Comment: Hello! I wasn't familiar with the library you mentioned. I'll study the documentation a bit, and if I can't solve the problem, I'll come back here to ask for help. At least now I have an idea of what might work.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your help with the documentation and examples. I was able to implement my automation project after studying these materials. Thank you very much!